# Getting nunique percentage instead of count from a column

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe with a column with repeating values and another column with categories against them.

Sample dataframe:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [101,102,103,101,104,106,102,103,104,105,106],
                    'col2': ['A','B','A','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],
                    'col3': [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,912,123,234],
                   })
```

What I need is to get the a table with unique values from col2 as index or as a column, and in second column the count of unique values under that category in col1.

Expected Outcome for above sample:

```
A    0.5
B    0.5
```

I can get the unique values count under col2 using this. However, I need this in percentage format.

```
df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].nunique()
```

Can I do that by adding a function to .apply() in this line of code itself or through some other method or function?

I do not want to create a new variable for this nunique() series/dataframe and then create a new column for percentage using operations through another line of code. Any way to do this in the above line of code itself?

Comment: For example, value_counts() has a normalize argument that can return percentage instead of counts. Any way I can do that in nunique()?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as correct if we could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find one way to do this with a single statement:

```
(df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].nunique() / df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].nunique().sum())
```

This will return the expected output of unique value percentages instead of number (count) as under:

```
A    0.5
B    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, hope I got your question right:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df  = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [101,102,103,101,104,106,102,103,104,105,106],
                    'col2': ['A','B','A','A','A','B','B','A','A','B','B'],
                    'col3': [123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890,912,123,234],
                   })
grouped_list: pd.Series = df.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].apply(list)
unique_cnt = grouped_list.apply(lambda content: {key: value / len(content) for key, value in Counter(content).items()})
unique_cnt_df = unique_cnt.apply(pd.Series)
```

It might not be the most resource efficient if you have many cells to handle, but gets the job done in an elegant way. Depending on which format is better for you, you may use either the variable unique_cnt which is a pd.Series of dicts or unique_cnt_df which is a pd.DataFrame where A, B, ... are index and 101, 102, ... as columns (some cells are NaN since no corresponding record exists).

```
# unique_cnt
col2
A    {101: 0.333, 103: 0.333, 104: 0.333}
B    {102: 0.4,   106: 0.4,   105: 0.2}

# unique_cnt_df
           101  102       103       104  105  106
col2                                             
A     0.333333  NaN  0.333333  0.333333  NaN  NaN
B          NaN  0.4       NaN       NaN  0.2  0.4
```

Comment: I am sure this does the work if I need the percentage of values in col1 to its total under category from col2. However, I just need the percentage distribution of values in col1 under categories (groups) from col2.